# Inventory options have disappeared on Minecraft PC edition

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-mods

When I press <kbd>e</kbd> in Minecraft, all that pops up is a box containing my inventory, my equipped armor, and a crafting table.

The other options, such as changing the time of day and the inventory button that appears to the bottom left, are gone. Have these just been removed, or have I accidentally toggled them off?

Comment: Have I missed something or are you talking about a mod? Vanilla Minecraft never had any kind of button to change the time or a button with "Inventory" written on it.

Comment: None of those options are in vanilla Minecraft. They are, however, in the mod TooManyItems as well as NotEnoughItems- if you want them back, you'll have to install those (unless you were using some other mod for them).

Comment: I am currently playing attack of the B team from Technic launcher, if that helps.

Comment: Press 'o' with your inventory open

Comment: See http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/191875/75275

Answer (score 1):

You are using the mod [Not Enough Items](http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/mapping-and-modding/minecraft-mods/1279956-chickenbones-mods), which is included in the Attack of the B-Team modpack. To toggle the inventory additions, you have to press a key (<kbd>O</kbd> by default, can be changed in the NEI options).